# How to sort a Datagrid in WPF MVVM without one row?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to sort a datagrid without last row. This last row must come at last in both ascending and descending sorting

I have tried Sorting event and used LINQ to separate the last row based on the property. But I am unable to keep the row at last.

Comment: Sounds like you may need another sort criteria

Comment: Can you tell me how to change the sort criteria? I'm new to WPF and MVVM. How to change the sort description in MVVM?